# If $f'(x)<2f(x)$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1$. Then $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(x)dx$ lies in the interval

Tags: calculus

> Let $\displaystyle f:\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be positive, non-constant and Diff. function such that $f'(x)<2f(x)$
>
> and $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1$. Then value of $\displaystyle \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(x)dx$ lies in the interval.
>
> $(a)\;\; \left(2e-1\;,2e\right)\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; \left(e-1\;,2e-1\right)\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; \displaystyle \left(\frac{e-1}{2},e-1\right)\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\; \displaystyle \left(0,\frac{e-1}{2}\right)$.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\displaystyle f'(x)<2f(x)\Rightarrow \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}<2\Rightarrow \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx<2\int 1\cdot dx$

So We Get $\displaystyle \ln \left|f(x)\right| <2x+\ln |c|\Rightarrow \ln \left |\frac{f(x)}{c}\right|<2x\Rightarrow f(x)<ce^{2x}.$

Now Put $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{2}\;,$ We Get $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)<c\cdot e\Rightarrow 1<c\cdot e$

So We get $\displaystyle c>\frac{1}{e}$.

Now How can I solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Now we have$$\int_{1/1}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx<c\int_{1/2}^{1}e^{2x}dx=\frac{c}{2}\left(e^{2}-e\right)<\frac{e-1}{2}$$
 and obviously if $f$
  is positive, then$$0<\int_{1/2}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx$$
 so the right answer is $(d)$.